# Prevent going to top of page after menu button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a fixed menu button that displays the menu items when is clicked. The problem is that when is clicked, it always goes to the top of the page just before the menu is open. I have tried width `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` but nothing happens. I think there should be a way to detect the scroll position to keep the menu div sticky at the same position where is open on the page. Also, note that I applied `overflow:hidden` to the body and HTML to keep them fixed when the menu button is clicked.

```js
$(".nav-mobile-toggle").click(function() {
  $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28.6px;
  color: #005153;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-mobile-toggle pt8" data-modal-id data-notification-link="nav-slide">
  <div class="btn--menu">
    <span class="h6 nombre">Menu</span>
    <i class="icon-Align-Right icon icon--sm"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="notification pos-right pos-top nav-slide col-sm-4 col-xs-12 bg--primary-1" data-notification-link="nav-slide" data-animation="from-right" id="notification">
  <div class="nav-slide__content">
    <div class="pt104 text-left">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="/">
            <span class="h3">Inicio</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/el-despacho.php">
            <span class="h3">El despacho</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/quienes-somos.php">
            <span class="h3">Quiénes somos</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/que-nos-diferencia.php">
            <span class="h3">Qué nos diferencia</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/lo-que-opinan.php">
            <span class="h3">Qué opinan de nosotros</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/areas-practica.php">
            <span class="h3">Áreas de práctica</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/blog">
            <span class="h3">Blog</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/contacto.php">
            <span class="h3">Contacta con nosotros</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="pos-absolute pos-bottom menu-footer text-right">
      <p class="tel">
        <a href="tel:123456789" style="text-decoration:none;">123 456 789</a>
      </p>
      <p class="mail">
        <a href="mailto:info@example.com" style="text-decoration:none;">info@example.com</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `event` parameter into the function:

```
$(".nav-mobile-toggle").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```